# Graphics problems in Ubuntu 14.04, distorted text

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 with a nvidia GTX 660 graphics cards. My system had been working fine till yesterday when the graphics started going crazy (see link attached for image) after running the computer for like 10 minutes.

[image: Font look bad]

Im running a dual boot with windows 8 and I can use that and play games without a problem so Im thinking it's not a hardware issue.

I updated the graphic cards drivers and used different drivers to no avail. I then reinstalled ubuntu, on both a different HD and on the same HD and the problem persists.

I've looked online and haven't found anything similar, any help or insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to install bumblebee and nvidia

are u using 64bit architecture? if yes install nvidia from it
http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.59-driver.html

if not download here
http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-295.59-driver

and install bumblebee

sudo apt-get install bumblebee